# CommonsChunkPlugin - webpack failed to compile - with errors like -'error in multi'

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

Everything was working fine with webpack2, until I tried to use CommonsChunkPlugin. This is my webpack.config

```
var path = require("path");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var LiveReloadPlugin = require("webpack-livereload-plugin");
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
var pkg = require("./package.json");
var webpack = require("webpack");

//new UglifyJsPlugin({ sourceMap: false })
var baseConfig = {
  entry: {
    bundle: "./src/index",
    vendor: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies),
    load: "./src/load"
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@rzr-ui": path.join(__dirname, "src/rzr-ui/src/js/ui/")
    },
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  devServer: {
    headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }
  },
  plugins: [

    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: "vendor",
      minChunks: function (module) {
        // this assumes your vendor imports exist in the node_modules directory
        return module.context && module.context.indexOf("node_modules") !== -1;
      }
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
   ......
```

and I am getting these errors. Cannot understand what is reason behind

```
WARNING in ./~/npm-check/lib/in/read-package-json.js
9:14-31 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./~/depcheck/dist/constants.js
24:18-72 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./~/depcheck/dist/utils/index.js
27:9-26 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./~/depcheck/dist/utils/index.js
44:11-26 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8000 @hotelsoft/common @hotelso... ... ...
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@hotelsoft/common' in '/Users/vishal/Documents/visdWorkspace/spydr-ui'
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8000 @hotelsoft/common @hotelsoft/icons @ho... ... ... .....

ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8000 @hotelsoft/common @hotelso... ... ...
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'font-awesome' in '/Users/vishal/Documents/visdWorkspace/spydr-ui'
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8000 @hotelsoft/common @hotelsoft/icons @ho... ... ... .....

ERROR in ./~/react-tab/lib/index.js
Module parse failed: /Users/vishal/Documents/visdWorkspace/spydr-ui/node_modules/react-tab/lib/index.js Unexpected token (7:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     render: function () {
|         return (
|             <div>Tab</div>
|         );   
|     }
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8000 @hotelso.... ... ...

ERROR in ./~/path-exists/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/vishal/Documents/visdWorkspace/spydr-ui/node_modules/path-exists'
 @ ./~/path-exists/index.js 2:9-22
 @ ./~/npm-check/lib/in/create-package-summary.js
 @ ./~/npm-check/lib/in/index.js
 @ ./~/npm-check/lib/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8000 @hotelsoft/comm .... .... .....

ERROR in ./~/depcheck/dist/check.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/vishal/Documents/visdWorkspace/spydr-ui/node_modules/depcheck/dist'
 @ ./~/depcheck/dist/check.js 13:10-23
 @ ./~/depcheck/dist/index.js
 @ ./~/npm-check/lib/in/get-unused-packages.js
 @ ./~/npm-check/lib/in/index.js
 @ ./~/npm-check/lib/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8000 @hotelsoft/com
```

Hoping someone here can help me